# 2010's flash game, either on Discovery/History Channel website

Tags: story-identification, video-games

This game was similar to a tower-defense game.  The towers however, were in a fixed position and could be controlled by the player/computer/neutral depending on whose resources were occupying the area at that time.  The game had multiple levels where the goal would be to defeat a military commander or some sort of mythical monster.  You'd start in your spawn and across the map there would be neutral areas where you'd drag from your spawn to those towers where resources are stored.  The spawn could only send the resources it had available at a time, and resources would add up (represented by a number above each tower) showing how many you could send at a time. Once you had control of the resource you could then drag from that tower to another tower to either add resources (if you control that tower), or remove resources if it was computer controlled.

I remember one level was a Kraken.  You had towers in between the head and the tentacles.  The tentacles would hit the towers to deplete resources and you'd send resources from the towers to hurt the tentacles.